# HTMLdrop down for PHP database values

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm storing my database values in a PHP file as follows:

```
$select->from(apartment,array('idapartment'));   
$select->where('apartment.idowner = ?',$usersession->arrvar['idowner']);
$stmt = $select->query();   
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$this->view->$rows = $options;
```

Now I want to use this in a dropdown in a phtml file .Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: Maybe read the part after Zend_Db called [Zend_From](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html)...

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Comment: sorry some comments which i posted got missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is assuming that you are fetching the results as an associative array.  If you are fetching them as an object, use `$row->idapartment` instead of `$row['idapartment']`

```
<select>
<?php foreach($this->rows as $row): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['idapartment']; ?>"><?php echo $row['idapartment']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

in a php file you simply write html code using the echo statement.

such as:

```
echo "<SELECT>";
for($i=0$i<count($result);$i++){
    echo "<option>".$result[$i]['idowner']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```